# Why aren't local variables within nested functions associated?

Tags: bioinformatics, local-variables, dna-sequence

Could someone please explain why local variables passed to the same nested function give different results.

The following function `import_alignment()` includes a conditional block `if trimref:` which changes the input data and calls the function again on this new data.

When I wrote this function it appeared to do the expected manipulations but returned the original data.

I've just realised that I neglected to assign results returned from the second call to the associated variables.

originally `import_alignment(modified *args)` now...

`sequences, numseqs, refseq, refname = import_alignment(modified *args)`

Which does what it should, but I'm still not sure why the first version didn't work.

...more details...

The function imports DNA sequence data from a Fasta file (a text file with >name and sequence on alternate lines), and returns list of sequences, along with the sequence count, and the name and sequence of a gap-free reference (the first sequence in the file).

It first calls the numseqs() function which does a basic quality check on the input file.

It then opens the file, assigns the odd lines to the sequences list (lines 0, 2, 4,... are sequence names; 1, 3, 5 are sequences), extracts the reference name and removes gaps ('-') from the reference sequence.

It then tests whether  `trimref == True` if so then it harvests the sequence names from the file,

`trim_TOref() removes reference gap positions from all sequences

`output_data()` writes the resulting sequence alignment to a new fasta file (name_trimmed.fas)

this file is then passed back to `import_alignment()` to extract the modified sequences

```
def import_alignment(filename, path, trimref=True):
    """
    this function extracts sequences from a fasta file and does basic QC
    """
    infile = path + filename
    filesize = file_size(infile)
    print("Input path and filename : ",infile)
    print("File Size : {0}".format(filesize))
    numseqs = check_even(infile)
    try:
        with open(infile) as f:
            f.seek(0)
            sequences = pick_lines(f, odds=True)
            refseq = sequences[0].replace("-","")
            f.seek(0)
            refname = f.readline().strip('>\n')
            if trimref:           
                f.seek(0)
                seqnames = pick_lines(f, False)
                sequences = trim_TOref(sequences)
                outfile = filename[0:-4] + "_trimmed"
                output_data(outfile, sequences, outpath = (path + 'output/'), filetype = '.fas', keys = seqnames)
                trimref = False
                sequences, numseqs, refseq, refname = import_alignment((outfile + '.fas'), outpath, trimref)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found. Check the path variable and filename")
        exit()
    return sequences, numseqs, refseq, refname
```

Comment: including the language you are using (python3) as a tag is kinda important

Comment: your function is "recursive", it is calling itself. it is doing so within a `try` which may mean whenever it runs out of resources it returns ... a classic stackoverflow

Comment: My guess it you want to loop over the fasta then call your function exactly once per  sequence,  not call your function from within your function.

Comment: Thanks @tomc - oops yes, Python3! I've got it working nicely now. It wasn't a stackoverflow but hierarchical local variables. Unless the results of the inner function call (conditional, not iterative) are assigned to the variables in the outer function, it returns their previous values.